# locationProvider html5mode is not working

Tags: angularjs

I m using modularized routes and I want to remove the # tag from my URL. But as most articles says I added this code into my route

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

  // use the HTML5 History API
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

})
```

and I added this to my master page(index.html)

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
 <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
 <!-- bower:css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet"         href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
 <!-- endbower -->
 <!-- endbuild -->
 <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
 <!-- endbuild -->
 <base href="/">
</head>
```

and I added base tag too. But the problem is when I enter the url like this

```
https://localhost:9000/loginselect
```

it says

```
Cannot GET /loginselect
```

But if I enter this as below(as previus) its working

```
https://localhost:9000/#/loginselect
```

but it shows the Url as

```
https://localhost:9000/loginselect
```

but when I refresh again the same error occurs. Could any one help me. I m using requireJs for loading files and modularized route files are loading using requireJs

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your server to serve index.html on that path.

html5Mode only sets Angulars behaviour when it comes to non-fragmented urls, but Angular only handles things -after- the first request, since on the first request the page and the javascript has not even loaded yet. The first request always hits the server, so when you enter the url `https://localhost:9000/loginselect` directly a request will be sent to the server, and if the server doesn't recognise the url you will get an error.

To solve this you need to configure your server to server your index.html file for that url, and for any other url your app uses. Typically you will set the server to sent index.html on any url except for those matching static assets, like images. If you do that, then on these urls the server will load index.html, Angular will start, and Angular will handle the route.

The reason it works for `https://localhost:9000/#/loginselect` is that by convention servers will ignore the fragment part of the url, i.e. '#/loginselect`. So the server grabs whatever is on / (since it ignores the rest) which is probably index.html. Angular then kicks in and handles the fragment part.

**Edit:**

To do this in nginx I would use something like this:

```
location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

This checks if there is a file on the path given (so if you ask for a static resource like an image it will give you that) and if it can't find one it will serve index.html instead.

Note that this is the simplest possible case and it has the drawback of serving your index.html on ANY 404. You could also be more specific and exclude certain directories (like /assets or /static) instead of doing a try_files. Then you could still have a 404 if you try to get a static asset that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok. Think I want to directly go to the **https://localhost:9000/loginselect** url directly by just entering that url (**https://localhost:9000/loginselect**) and press enter. Currently it's not working as I said. If I entered  (**https://localhost:9000/#/loginselect**) it work.  I want to directly go to the **https://localhost:9000/loginselect** url directly by just entering that url (**https://localhost:9000/loginselect**) and press enter. Could you please tell me how to configure my server for this?

Comment: It depends entirely on your server. I'll add how to do it in nginx, don't really know for other things.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running Apache on the server you can put this in your .htaccess file which should allow you to directly go to any valid url. But seriously, I have worked for over a year with Angular now in a professional environment: nobody cares about the `#` in the url. It is easier to leave it there than trying to remove it.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(cssÂ¦js|html|png) #Add extra extensions needed.
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: It may have SEO implications (with emphasis on may, I have never tested this properly). The Google and Bing crawlers can read a page using html5mode, but I am not sure if they can read a page without. The new ajax crawling is based on pushstates, which I don't think Angular uses when html5mode is not on. Also, I care! Fragments are implementation details that should be hidden from the end-user. Unless it's an internal admin... then I couldn't care less :)